# Getting a 'char cannot be dereferenced error' when compiling code using .toUpperCase();

Tags: java, char, dereference

im new to java and am writing a program that will let you input your first and last name and will give you your initials, but i want the intitials to always be in upper case.

I get a "char cannot be dereferenced" error whenever i run the code.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class InitialHere
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Scanner getInput = new Scanner (System.in);
            String firstName;
            String lastName;
            char firstInitial;
            char lastInitial;

            System.out.println("What is your first name?");
            System.out.println();
            firstName = getInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Thankyou, what is your last name?");
            System.out.println();
            lastName = getInput.nextLine();

            firstInitial = firstName.charAt(0);
            lastInitial = lastName.charAt(0);
            firstInitial = firstInitial.toUpperCase();
            lastInitial = lastInitial.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Your initials are " + firstInitial + "" + lastInitial + ".");

        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is a `toUpperCase` method on a `char`? Or in fact any methods at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, primitives have no methods, only their boxed types do. If you want to get the uppercase version of a `char`, the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class has a method just for that: [`Character.toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)):

```
 firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(firstInitial);
```

(Do the same for `lastInitial`)

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou. I decided to just turn the string last and first Name to all uppercase. I dont want to run before i can crawl.

Answer (score 0):

`firstInitial` is of type `char` which has no method `toUpperCase`.  (Being a primitive, it has no methods at all.)  Call [`toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) on the original `String` instead.

**Update (see comments):**  The documentation of [`Character.toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) says:

> In general, `String.toUpperCase()` should be used to map characters to uppercase.  `String` case mapping methods have several benefits over `Character` case mapping methods.  `String` case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the `Character` case mapping methods cannot.

Therefore, the most robust approach would be to use

```
String firstName = firstName.trim();  // ignore leading white space
final String firstInitial = firstName.substring(0, firstName.offsetByCodePoints(0, 1)).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Not quite right, the OP needs to call [`Character.toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)).

Comment: Why would that be “more correct”?  There could be a problem if the name starts with a character that has an uppercase representation worth more than one character.  But in this case, the most robust approach would be to convert the extracted first character into a string and then call `toUpperCase` on that string.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
firstInitial = (char) (firstInitial >= 97 && firstInitial <= 122 ? firstInitial - 32 : firstInitial);
lastInitial = (char) (lastInitial >= 97 && lastInitial <= 122 ? lastInitial - 32 : lastInitial);
```

Comment: That seems extremely complicated, and too be honest i don't think it even works :P

Comment: @Dylex It definitely works. The `char` between 97 and 122 represents a to z, while the one between 65 to 90 is A to Z. So just minus 32 to get the upper-case character.

Comment: It works if ASCII characters is all that concerns you.